# Improving performance (speed) of a function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a database of patients and their results.
Below are demo dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

data =  [[1 , '20210201', 4567, 40],
         [1 , '20210604', 4567, 55],
         [1 , '20200405', 2574, 42],
         [1 , '20210602', 2574, 55],
         [2 , '20210201', 4567, 25],
         [2 , '20210604', 4567, 32],
         [2 , '20200405', 2574, 70],
         [2 , '20210602', 2574, 46]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'date', 'test_id', 'result'])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d') # format date field
df

   id       date  test_id  result
0   1 2021-02-01     4567      40
1   1 2021-06-04     4567      55
2   1 2020-04-05     2574      42
3   1 2021-06-02     2574      55
4   2 2021-02-01     4567      25
5   2 2021-06-04     4567      32
6   2 2020-04-05     2574      70
7   2 2021-06-02     2574      46

data =  [[1 , '20220101'],
         [2 , '20220102']]

customers = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'start_date'])
customers.start_date = pd.to_datetime(customers.start_date, format='%Y%m%d') # format date field
print(customers)

   id start_date
0   1 2022-01-01
1   2 2022-01-02
```

And the following function that gets a customer and its initial date and returns aggregated results regarding each test in a specific time period before the initial date:

```
def patient_agg_results(df, patient_ID, X, Y, firstAF):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    X_date = firstAF - pd.DateOffset(months=X)
    Y_date = firstAF - pd.DateOffset(months=X+Y)
    # get results of specific patient within the timeframe
    patient_results = df[(df['id'] == patient_ID) & (df['date'] < X_date) & (df['date'] > Y_date)]  # ***
    if (len(patient_results) > 0 ):
        # Calculate mean
        curr_result = pd.DataFrame(patient_results.groupby('test_id').mean()['result'])
        curr_result = curr_result.set_index(curr_result.index.astype(str) + '_mean')
        result = pd.concat([result,curr_result])
        # Calculate newest result
        curr_result = pd.DataFrame(patient_results.groupby('test_id').max()['result'])
        curr_result = curr_result.set_index(curr_result.index.astype(str) + '_new')
        result = pd.concat([result,curr_result])
        # Calculate oldest result
        curr_result = pd.DataFrame(patient_results.groupby('test_id').min()['result'])
        curr_result = curr_result.set_index(curr_result.index.astype(str) + '_old')
        result = pd.concat([result,curr_result])
        # Calculate STD
        curr_result = pd.DataFrame(patient_results.groupby('test_id').std()['result'])
        curr_result = curr_result.set_index(curr_result.index.astype(str) + '_std')
        result = pd.concat([result,curr_result])
        # Calculate slope
        patient_results['int_date'] = pd.to_datetime(patient_results['date']).astype(np.int64) # create integer date
        curr_result = pd.DataFrame(patient_results.groupby('test_id')['result', 'int_date'].apply(lambda v: linregress(v.int_date, v.result)[0]))
        curr_result.columns = ['result']
        curr_result = curr_result.set_index(curr_result.index.astype(str) + '_slope')
        result = pd.concat([result,curr_result])
        result['id'] = patient_ID
    return result.to_dict()
```

I use the function like that:

```
customers['lab_results'] = customers.apply(lambda row: patient_agg_results(df,row['id'],12,12,row['start_date']),axis=1)
```

The problem is that my original datasets include about a million patients and a few million results which takes this code to run for a few days.
The most time consuming line is the filtering line (comment: ***)

Any idea how to make it more time efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question.  Usually when the data is all in memory and then things run for days it is because they have run into an execution combinatorial nightmare.  Your pointer to the selection line as the biggest time consumer makes total sense – that this is a CPU-bound process.

If you assume that the `df` has 3 million rows, then in that filter line – since it is part of an `apply` function – there are 9 million comparisons that then happens 1 million times.  That’s a big number that could lead to days of execution.  Spark is excellent at handling large data but I suspect that you will have this same CPU-bound combinatorial nightmare in Spark.

You may reap huge benefits by approaching this from the other direction – a `groupby` from `df`.

`df.grouby('id').apply(…)`

The `apply` function from `groupby` will receive a full sub-frame of all the columns and rows for each `id`.  With this approach you will be doing a date selection on an average of 3 rows times 2 and not 3 million times 2 for each `id`.  And the repeated 3 million-row `id` selection completely goes away.  It is handled once during the initial `groupby` operation.

Within the `df.groupby.apply` function you could lookup what you need from the `customer` data frame by using `customer.at[id, 'start_date']`.  (After you set the `customer` data frame’s index to `id` - which would speed things up)

There may be some savings by consolidating your set of `groupby` calls in your  function to instead use one `groupby.agg()` instead.  Though didn’t get a chance to fully digest that to come up with a more solidified suggestion.

Once you get the combinations under control you can go here for some great ways to improve performance:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

Man, I love this kind of problem!  I wish I had more time.

**Here is some starter code to communicate this idea**

```
customers = customers.set_index('id')

def jch_agg_result(gf, X, Y):
    firstAF = customers.at[gf['id'].iat[0], 'start_date']
    X_date = firstAF - pd.DateOffset(months=X)
    Y_date = firstAF - pd.DateOffset(months=X+Y)
    
    patient_results = gf[(gf['date'] < X_date) & (gf['date'] > Y_date)] 
    
    if (len(patient_results) > 0 ):
        tid = gf['test_id'].iat[0]
        m = {f'{tid}_mean': gf['result'].mean(), f'{tid}_max': gf['result'].max()}
        return m
    
    return np.nan
```

Then:

```
df.groupby(['id','test_id']).apply(jch_agg_result,12,12).dropna()

id  test_id
1   2574       {'2574_mean': 48.5, '2574_max': 55}
2   2574       {'2574_mean': 58.0, '2574_max': 70}
```

You'd then just need to merge back in the applicable date to get to your desired result.  And - not sure if I got the inner mean, max, etc right but it is there so you can modify to meet your needs.

Comment: Updated my answer to include some starter code.

Comment: This works great!! Thanks for the great advice and for the positive nature of your answer!!

Comment: @gtomer Excellent!  Glad to hear that this worked out for you.  Thanks for taking the time to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark should be able to help you out. There may be other, faster solutions, but this will be quick to both run and implement. Most of the functions are generally similar between the PySpark and Pandas, and in my experience on large datasets with simple operations like this, PySpark should help you out.

Comment: I am not familiar with PySpark. What are the equivalent of pd.DataFrame and pd.read_csv?

Comment: spark.sparkContext.textFile() would be the way to read in a csv, which would create a Resilient Distributed Dataset.
https://acme.byu.edu/00000180-6d79-d2d1-ade4-6f7979cd0001/sparks
The link has my first exposure to the system and a few pointers on how to set everything up.